# Windows Azure SDK for C++

Tags: c++, linux, azure, sdk, azure-storage-queues

Part of my project is worker application written in C++, running on Linux.
I just find out that MS doesn't provide C++ version of Windows Azure SDK.
I need to access Windows Azure Storage Queue.

Is there any C++ port of SDK?
Is there any chance to use SDK from other language (i.e. python, node.js)?
Or the best option is to use REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casablanca is preparing library for Linux/C++. Check out http://casablanca.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Linux%20Features&referringTitle=FAQ

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft released a preview of a C++ SDK for Azure; details are available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/20/windows-azure-storage-client-library-for-cplusplus-preview.aspx). Source code is on [Github](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-storage-cpp). The currently available preview doesn't compile out-of-the-box for Linux, but the changes required to make it work are pretty minimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Azure Storage via many langueage SDK
 - http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-storage-libraries-in-many-languages

I think better way than REST API is to use node.js SDK like below
 - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/queue-service/
 - http://d.hatena.ne.jp/waritohutsu/20120212/1329021441

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that using node.js code from C++ is better way than using raw REST API (basing on others sdks source code)

Answer (score 0):

The Azure SDK team is working on C++ client libraries for Azure Storage and Key Vault, as well as a few other libraries. These libraries are currently in *preview*. The complete list is [here](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/#c), which includes links to the source code in the Azure SDK C++ repo and API reference docs.